# jsTree -prevent parent node from opening when creating a new node

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a tree created with jquery jstree(1.0).
When I create a new node inside a certain parent node in the tree, the parent node is opened by default. I would like to know how to prevent the parent node from opening.
I tried using "open_onmove": false, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

That's the standard behaviour and looking in the codes i can't see an option for getting around it. Assuming you're using the `element.jstree('create'..)` command you usually want to bring up the input field right away for inputting the new folder name, and that would look weird if it didn't expand the parent.

I'm not sure what your exact case is but looking in the code you have this line around 1340 in jstree 1.0-RC3

```
if(p.length && p.hasClass("jstree-closed")) { this.open_node(p, false, true); }
```

Where `p` is parent. So basically it's opening the node if not already open. If you want to stay out of modding the jstree file itself (which you probably want to), i'd suggest a workaround where you try to remove or manipulate the `.jstree-closed` class of the parent element just before you add your new node, and then replace the class in the callback part of `element.jstree('create'..)` or `jstree.create_node(...)`, whichever you're using.

Comment: I did use a workaround..I listen for the "before.jstree" event, and if the operation is "open_node", then I prevent the operation from executing in the desired cases (conditioned by a prevent_open variable). Thanks for the suggestions.